# How do I write the code for the variable BUY that I have in strategy.entry I will use this code to write the Variable BUY code

Tags: linear-regression, pine-script, pine-script-v5, operands

I have these variables that I want to be able to choose from in a drop down input under option for Line1 and Line2. These should be selectable using yet another drop down input with `options = ['none', '==', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=' , 'crossover', 'crossunder'])` named Operator1.

```
sm1res = input.timeframe(title='Time for open', defval='30')
sm1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, sm1res, open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
sm2res = input.timeframe(title='Time for open', defval='60')
sm2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, sm2res, open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
sm3res = input.timeframe(title='Time for open', defval='240')
sm3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, sm3res, open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

to1res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous open 1', defval='30')  
to1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, to1res, open[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 
to2res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous open 2', defval='60')  
to2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, to2res, open[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
to3res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous open 3', defval='240') 
to3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, to3res, open[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)  

th1res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous high 1', defval='30') 
th1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, th1res, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)  
th2res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous high 2', defval='60') 
th2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, th2res, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 
th3res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous high 3', defval='240')  
th3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, th3res, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 

tl1res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous low 1', defval='30')
tl1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tl1res, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
tl2res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous low 2', defval='60')
tl2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tl2res, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
tl3res = input.timeframe(title='Time for previous low 3', defval='240')
tl3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tl3res, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


Line1 = input.string(defval = "sm1", title = 'Line1', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options=["sm1", "sm2", "sm3", "to1", "to2", "to3", "th1", "th2", "th3", "tl1", "tl2", "tl3"])
Operator1 = input.string(defval = 'none', title = 'Operator1', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options = ['none', '==', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=', 'crossover', 'crossunder'])
Line2 = input.string(defval = none, title = 'Line2', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options=["sm1", "sm2", "sm3", "to1", "to2", "to3", "th1", "th2", "th3", "tl1", "tl2", "tl3"])
```

Then I have a buy variable but can't get it to work with different attempts of code, sometimes it says it should be series string, bool, const string, Syntax error at input ':' and a lot of other errors.

```
BUY = line1 : Operator1 : line2 ? : na
```

Then comes my order placement:

```
if BUY
    if Type == _S_
        strategy.close('S')
    else
        strategy.entry('K', strategy.long)

if SELL
    if Type == _L_
        strategy.close('K')
    else
        strategy.entry('S', strategy.short)
```

Grateful for help so that parts of the errors are with correct code instead and suggestions for improvements welcome. I'm not very good at programming, so please explain in a simple way if you have time.

I've tried reading the manual and looking for different allowed types that go together. I have also tried Pinecoders and the chat. I'm afraid request.security doesn't allow options.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. As it stands, it is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question so it contains only one question at a time.

Regarding your first question, you can use a `switch`:

```
Line1_input = input.string(defval = "sm1", title = 'Line1', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options=["sm1", "sm2", "sm3", "to1", "to2", "to3", "th1", "th2", "th3", "tl1", "tl2", "tl3"])
Line2_input = input.string(defval = "sm1", title = 'Line2', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options=["sm1", "sm2", "sm3", "to1", "to2", "to3", "th1", "th2", "th3", "tl1", "tl2", "tl3"])

Operator1 = input.string(defval = 'none', title = 'Operator1', inline = 'Operator1', group = 'Strategy1', options = ['none', '==', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=', 'crossover', 'crossunder'])

line1 = switch Line1_input
    "sm1" => ta.sma(close, 10)
    "sm2" => ta.ema(close, 10)
    => ta.hma(close, 10)

line2 = switch Line2_input
    "sm1" => ta.sma(close, 20)
    "sm2" => ta.ema(close, 20)
    => ta.hma(close, 20)

BUY = switch Operator1
    '==' => line1 == line2
    '<' => line1 < line2
    '>' => line1 > line2
    '<=' => line1 <= line2
    '>=' => line1 >= line2
    '!=' => line1 != line2
    'crossover' => ta.crossover(line1, line2)
    'crossunder' => ta.crossunder(line1, line2)
```

Comment: Hey! @mr_statler You probably misunderstood the technical solution, but with your code it was at least possible to compile the code. I have tried to insert a link with graph in this comment. To illustrate the technical solution. I absolutely do not want to include, for example => ta.ema(close, 10). Because then I don't compare sm1 with sm2. sm1 is barmerge 30 minutes and sm2 is barmerge 1H in this example. I want to be able to get a buy signal when sm1 is above sm2 and a sell signal when it's the other way around.

More text... next comment

[link](https://www.tradingview.com/x/2VmJTJ9s/)

Comment: If you click on the Link, a graph will appear!
It is important that there is a dropdown menu to be able to select sm1, sm2
etc. ... in the second you should be able to choose <, > etc... and in the last you should be able to choose sm1, sm2 etc...

An example of a result is sm1 > sm2.

I want to build a large logical strategy, so I need to be able to add many comparisons.

Comment: I have programmed a price variable that could perhaps be used instead of ta.ema(close, 10) but for example I have to use something similar to ta.ema(close, 10) but then my price variable must be used instead. The price variable is two pieces of hma 2 that are used to on a price as close to the truth as possible.

Comment: Just change my code example so that `"sm1" => sm1` , `"sm2" => sm2` and so on. The rest should work the same way

Comment: Thanks for the help, still working and maybe not learning! :-)